# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, dll, netbeans-8

Hi I'm getting this error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\hp\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JNI_C_App\output\JNI_App.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at jni_app.JNI_App.<clinit>(JNI_App.java:18)
```

Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1

how do i make a 64-bit dll, as jdk,OS and everything used is 64-bit?

Comment: It seems you have installed 64 bit java in a 32 bit OS or vice versa.

Comment: Correct. The Windows on Windows subsystem does not support linking 32-bit code with a 64-bit application. If you must use your 32-bit dll, then you must also use a 32-bit JRE/JDK.